# Are unitarily and orthogonally diagonalizable equivalent over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Over $\mathbb{C}$, are unitarily and orthogonally diagonalizable the same?

I know that unitary matrices are not necessarily orthogonal, but I can't find a counterexample to unitarily and orthogonally diagonalizable being the same. (Unitarily diagonalizable: $A=U^{-1}DU$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is complex and diagonal; replace unitary with orthogonal for orthogonally diagonalizable)

(Orthogonal: real unitary matrix)

Comment: To be clear, what do you mean by "orthogonal" here?  A unitary that has real entries?  Or a complex matrix $O$ such that $O^T=O^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider an orthogonal matrix (in $SO(2),$ if you like). Any such matrix is unitarily diagonalizable, and almost no such matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable (if it were, its eigenvalues would be $\pm 1.$

Comment: This seems to only apply when $D$ is real.